# What is the practical use of Callback class template?

Tags: c++, templates, callback

Im trying to understand all the usage of callbacks, but I stumbled upon this code here and I have a hard time understanding the good sides of this template class. In main I create a object of class FooBar, then I create a object of class CallBack, so I can call the method in FooBar. I think is doing extra work for nothing, because the object its already created(FooBar ob1), why not call the function directly?

```
 template <typename  T>
    class CallBack {
    public:
        public:
      typedef void (T::*methodcb)() const; //can you help me understand what the author did there?



  CallBack(): m_object(NULL), m_cb(NULL) {} 
  CallBack( T& object, methodcb cb) : m_object(&object), m_cb(cb)  {}

  void operator()(){ 
      if (m_object != NULL && m_cb != NULL) {
        (m_object->*m_cb)();
    }
  };

    private:
  T* m_object;
 methodcb m_cb;

};

class FooBar{

public:

void foo() const { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; } 
void bar() const { std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl; }

};
```

Comment: The callback allow to change the object and/or the method to call. Indeed in a simple example to show how it works, the example may be rewritten simply to not use the CallBack.

Answer (score 1):

Callback could help us decouple *what* gets done from *when* it gets done. Such as,

```
std::vector<CallBack<FooBar>> commands;

// initialize the commands
// in charge of sepecifying WHAT will be invoked
FooBar foobar;
commands.emplace_back(foobar, &FooBar::foo);
commands.emplace_back(foobar, &FooBar::bar);

// ... ...

// no need to know the details about functions
// in charge of controlling WHEN will be invoked
for (auto command : commands) {
    command();
}
```

or decreasing code repetiton,

```
void do_sth(CallBack<FooBar> c) {
    // do something before...
    c();
    // do something after...
}

FooBar foobar;
if () 
    do_sth(CallBack<FooBar>(foobar, &FooBar::foo));
else
    do_sth(CallBack<FooBar>(foobar, &FooBar::bar));
```

Callback is usually used in [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: hmm, this example is high level. Do you have a simpler one maybe?

Comment: thank you verry much, i will break it down and try to work on it.

Comment: @DraganItmSmoljan Hope it could help you.